# JQuery DateTimePicker attached to Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, jquery-callback

I am using the JQuery DateTime Picker addon http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker and when I set it up as shown in various examples using an input, it works fine. I would however like to have the popup display when a link is clicked and popup an alert with the chosen date/time when they select "Done".

I have tried the following...

```
    <script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#dtpicker').datetimepicker(
        {
            addSliderAccess: true,
            sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
        });
    });
    </script>

<a href="#" id="dtpicker">(+) Add Null Route</a>
```

Is it possible to add this to a link rather than a button? Is there any way for me to actually take the date/time that was picked and do something with it when the "Done" button is selected?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use  `<input id="dtpicker" value="" type="button"/>`  but being **type="button"** ? And try to use css at the button to get this look like as a link.Type "button" is working look here : http://jsfiddle.net/bLh26hwo/

**Styling an input to look like a link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/yhtrxjus/

The solution for the second part:
Built-in `onClose` event:

```
$('#slider_example').datetimepicker({
...
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert('ok');
    },
});
```

Alternative:Add `click()` eventto the `done` button like this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-close").click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: That seems to work pretty well, thanks! Do you have any idea on the second part of the question in terms of performing actions on the "Done" button?

Comment: Done .Look the solution plz.Updated.

Comment: Strangely that does not seem to be working but it is probably an issue somewhere on my end rather than the actual code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes it strange because if you try this one at the chrome console here http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ and then press a done button it alerts!Try it if you want and tell me.Thanks

Comment: Which example on that page do you mean? The content at http://pastie.org/9652582 looks correct doesn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63167/discussion-between-john-grivas-and-brett-powell).

Comment: The solution for the second part was easy: $('#slider_example').datetimepicker({
...
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert('ok');
    },
});